# Virtual classes in diamond inheritance with multiple classes in between base class and most derived class

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

Okay so in the classic diamond inheritance example you have a base class, two classes that inherit from that base class and then another class that inherits from those two, making a nice symmetrical diamond. In that case the two classes inherit virtually from the base class to avoid having two copies of the base class in the most derived class.

But what if there are multiple levels of inheritance in between the base class and the most derived class, as seen in the example diagram below. Do all the classes (B, C, D) need to inherit virtually from their direct base classes or just the ones that are inherit directly (B, C) from the base class? Assuming there are no other classes besides the ones in the diagram.

[image]

Comment: This is a rather tricky question. I'd say that virtual inheritance should not be used and that it is the diamond inheritance that is flawed.

Comment: Just a bit about terminology; it's not the **classes** that are virtual, but the **inheritance**. So `class B : virtual public A` says that `A` is a virtual base of `B`. `A` is just a class; there's nothing virtual about it.

Comment: I'm programming a game and my class layout is such that I need to inherit in this manner. It's come up many times that composition is the better way to go rather than complex inheritance, but I was already too deep in implementation this was so I just want to finish this project using inheritance and will use composition in future projects :) @user7860670

Comment: When the only information we have about the classes in the hierarchy is that their names are `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`, it's impossible to say where virtual inheritance should be used. It depends on the **purpose** of the classes. For example, if class `A` is a base class that's used as a node in a list, you could have a list of `E` objects, in which case you want virtual inheritance, or you could have a list of `B` objects and a list of `C` objects, in which case you don't want virtual inheritance (since an `E` object is **both** a `B` object and a `C` object).

Comment: @user7860670 How is diamond inheritance "flawed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One does not need to declare `C` as virtual, since what virtual does is ensure that the class declared as such is contained exactly once, and `C` is only inherited from once. Basically, the only inheritances that need to be virtual are

```
class B : public virtual A { ... };
class C : public virtual A { ... };
```

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class

Comment: I think you've got the inheritance direction wrong, A is the base class and E is the most derived class

Comment: oh sorry. Edited.

Comment: But you have to be a bit more careful here. Virtual inheritance does not guarantee that the base class is contained exactly once. It guarantees that all uses of that class **as a virtual base** refer to a single object. You can also inherit non-virtually from the same class, and you'll get a separate base object for each non-virtual base. If that sounds like double-talk, ignore it. This isn't the place to write that sort of class hierarchy. <g>

Comment: That's why both B and C have to inherit virtually from A. In E, the only class that would've been included multiple times would be A, so that is the only one that needs to be virtual, and every inheritance from it, which is what I did. As you said, all uses of the class as a virtual base will refer to a single object, so in E, all uses of A are virtual this way, and therefore refer to a single object.

Comment: @PeteBecker can you give me an example? I have more classes than inherit from A non-virtually, but class E this is the only case where the classes create a diamond inheritance

Comment: @Yiannis -- don't get hung up on "diamond". That's shorthand for a common case. The thing you have to be careful about occurs when a class hierarchy involves inheriting from a base class more than once (whether it's a diamond or not). You have to decide which of those uses of the base class should be separate bases and which should not. Having a "diamond* does not mean you have to use virtual inheritance. Sometimes you want two separate bases of the same type, and sometimes you don't. There's no magic formula; it's a design decision, and depends on how the bases are used.

Comment: @Leonid I think you meant "One does not need to declare D as virtual"? You did declare C as virtual A in the code below

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for clarifying, in this particular design I have there is no case where I would want two separate copies of the base class A in a derived class

Comment: Re: "You did declare C as virtual A" -- that doesn't make `C` a virtual base class; it makes `A` a virtual base class. The only base that's repeated in this hierarchy is `A`, so that's the only one that's a candidate for being a virtual base. So neither `C` nor `D` should be a virtual base here.

Comment: @PeteBecker sorry, the inheritance of D from C and the inheritance of E from D and B do not need to be virtual, correct?

Comment: The **only** sensible candidates for virtual inheritance are bases that occur more than once in a class hierarchy.